# TFS consolidation migration

Tags: tfs

Consolidation several TFS servers into single server.

Any suggestions?   without any lossy data transfers, as it mentions in:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

All servers are running TFS2013

Answer (score 5):

If you want to consolidate "Servers" you can absolutely do it in a lossless manner.  If you want to consolidate Team Project Collections and/or Team Projects there is no supported way to do it in a lossless manner.

To consolidate servers you simply detach the Collection(s), then attach them to the target server.  A complete step-by-step is described in the ALM Rangers Upgrade Guidance (Pg 45): http://vsarupgradeguide.codeplex.com/